# How To Parse PHP Inside Other Filetypes On Windows Server 2008 IIS7?

Tags: windows, iis, php, iis-7, files

How would one treat a common .html file or .js file as .php in windows 2008 server running IIS 7?

I only want a specific filetype treated as .php - not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have PHP set up already (serving .php files)?  If so, can you add *.htm to the same handler mapping for *.php?